# sequelize.js consecutive many to many relationship

Tags: javascript, sql, sequelize.js

I have class A, B and C

A <- many to many -> B and B <- many to many-> C

For a single A, I want to find all the C related to A.

How do I write sequelize query such that it only does one single SQL call?

The many to many relationship is already defined in sequelize,
eg I can already do a.getBs(),  b.getCs(), or c.getBs()

I could obviously just write,

```
a.getBs()
.then(function(Bs) {
    return foreach(Bs, function(b) {return b.getCs();})
})
.then(function() {
    // flatten array of array of C here.
})
```

But this is doing too many SQL requests.

Also, what if I have an array of A? is there a way to just do a single SQL to return a map of {a1: ["c1", "c2"], a2: ["c2", "c99"] ...}

```
SELECT A.name, C.name as anotherName
FROM A
LEFT JOIN A_B ON A.id = A_B.A_id
LEFT JOIN B ON A_B.B_id = B.id
LEFT JOIN B_C ON B.id = B_C.B_id
LEFT JOIN C ON C.id = B_C.C_id
GROUP BY name, anotherName
```

I think this is the SQL I need, not sure how to generate it from sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

Sequelize joins associations mostly using includes and eager loading, so your query should look something like this:

```
A.findAll({
  where: { etc... }
  include: [
    {
      association: A.associations.B,
      include: [
        B.associations.C
      ]
    }
  ],
}).then((results) => {
  console.log(results[0].B[0].C[0]);
});
```